# Adicionando filhos a Stacklayout via MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Estou tentando gerar alguns campos Entry dentro de um StackLayout especifico, a ideia é quando clique no botão ele crie um novo Entry. o problema é que não consigo passar o BindingContext do StackLayout para minha ViewModel. retorna o seguinte erro.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS7OQ.png)

Codigo:

XAML

> ```
> <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding StacValores}">
>                               
> </StackLayout>
>
> <Button Text="Adicionar Valor Mensal" Command="{Binding BtnAddValorCommand}"/>
> ```

MVVM

> ```
>     public Command BtnAddValorCommand { get; }
>
>     public StackLayout _stacValores;
>     public StackLayout StacValores
>     {
>         get => _stacValores;
>         set
>         {
>             if (_stacValores == value)
>                 return;
>             _stacValores = value;
>             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_stacValores));
>         }
>     }
>
>     #endregion
>
>
>     #region Commands
>
>     public void AddEntryValor()
>     {
>         var novoStac = new StackLayout
>         {
>             Children =
>             {
>                 new Entry
>                 {
>                     Text = "Novo Entry",
>                     IsPassword = true,
>                 }
>             }
>         };
>         StacValores.Children.Add(novoStac);
>         
>     }
> ```

resumindo, como que eu posso adicionar um entry, ou outra coisa dentro de um stacklayout usando o MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

Deste jeito que você está fazendo, toda hora que clicar para criar uma `Entry`, será criado um `StackLayout` que envolve esta `Entry`.

Você pode colocar um `StackLayout` pra `Entry` no seu XAML (igual foi feito com a outra StackLayout que já está criada), retirar este `AddEntryValor()`, colocar um evento `Clicked` pro seu `Button` e no evento colocar o seguinte código:

```
public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 var entry = new Entry() { Text = "Campo Entry" };
 stackEntries.Children.Add(entry);
}
```